# How can I change UIStepper value when changed from UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uistepper

I'm very new to all of this and I found some code that got me understanding some of this syntax.  I'm trying to create a textfield that lets me type in a value that updates the stepper's value.  The stepper currently works (updates the uitextfield) but when I change the value in the textfield it doesn't update the stepper's value, so when I click on the stepper, it reverts back to whatever value it was before I typed in a value...  Can anyone tell me why the two functions STracksValueDidChange and CTrackValueDidChange have errors?

Here's my code so far:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var STracks: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var STracksStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var CTracks: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var CTrackStepper: UIStepper!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    STracksStepper.autorepeat = true
    STracksStepper.maximumValue = 100.0
    STracksStepper.minimumValue = 2.0
    STracksStepper.stepValue = 2.0
    print(STracksStepper.value)
    STracks.text = "\(Int(STracksStepper.value))"
    STracksStepper.addTarget(self, action: "SstepperValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    STracks.addTarget(self, action: "STextValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)


    CTrackStepper.autorepeat = true
    CTrackStepper.maximumValue = 100.0
    CTrackStepper.minimumValue = 2.0
    CTrackStepper.stepValue = 2.0
    print(CTrackStepper.value)
    CTracks.text = "\(Int(CTrackStepper.value))"
    CTrackStepper.addTarget(self, action: "CstepperValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    CTracks.addTarget(self, action: "CTextValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

}

//Steppers will update UITextFields
func SstepperValueDidChange(stepper: UIStepper) {

    let stepperMapping: [UIStepper: UITextField] = [STracksStepper: STracks]

    stepperMapping[stepper]!.text = "\(Int(stepper.value))"
}

func STracksValueDidChange(SText: UITextField) {

    let STextMapping: [UITextField: UIStepper] = [STracks: STracksStepper]

    STextMapping[SText]!.value = "(SText.text)"
}


func CstepperValueDidChange(stepper: UIStepper) {

    let stepperMapping: [UIStepper: UITextField] = [CTrackStepper: CTracks]

    stepperMapping[stepper]!.text = "\(Int(stepper.value))"
}


func CTrackValueDidChange(CText: UITextField) {

    let CTextMapping: [UITextField: UIStepper] = [CTracks: CTrackStepper]

    CTextMapping[CText]!.value = "(CText.text)"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: As I understand it, you want the updates to go in both directions.

Comment: Yes - both directions...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
CTrackStepper.value = Double(Textfield.text)
```

I am not so sure what the mapping is in your code.
But i don't think you need it for changing the value.

Update, made a project my self:

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func stepperValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
        textfield.text = String(sender.value)
    }

    @IBAction func valueChanged(sender: UITextField) {
        if Double(sender.text!) != nil {
            stepper.value = Double(sender.text!)!
        }
    }
}
```

For steppervaluechanged and valuechanged just drag from uistepper and textfield and choose action and change the Anyobject to Uistepper of Uitextfield.

Good luck :)

Comment: That link brings up two errors:
Value of optional type 'Double?' not unwrapped, did you mean to use ! or ?
and
Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped, did you mean to use ! or ?

Comment: CTrackStepper is mapped to the CTracks UITextField... is there a way to map it so that values change bidirectionally?

Comment: Never heard of mapping. But i gone try the to above